# Python decorator example

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am learning a bit about decorators from a great tutorial on [thecodeship](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) but have found myself rather confused by one example.

First a simple example followed by an explanation is given for what a decorator is.

```
def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
   return func_wrapper

def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)

print my_get_text("John")
```

Now this makes sense to me. A decorator is simply a wrapper to a function. And in this guys explanation he says a decorator is a function that takes another function as an argument, generates a new function, and returns the generated function to be used anywhere.

And now the equivalent to the above code is:

```
def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
   return func_wrapper

@p_decorate
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

print get_text("John")
```

I believe I understand the way a decorator is initialized when given no arguments. Correct me if I am wrong.

- The decorator by default passes in the function `get_text` and because `p_decorate` returns a function `func_wrapper`, we end up with the true statement `get_text = func_wrapper`.

What is important to me is the first code block equivalent, because I see and understand how the decorator is behaving.

What very much confuses me is the following code:

```
def tags(tag_name):
    def tags_decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(name):
            return "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(tag_name, func(name))
        return func_wrapper
    return tags_decorator

@tags("p")
def get_text(name):
    return "Hello "+name

print get_text("John")
```

Again, correct me if I'm wrong but this is my understanding.

- The decorator accepts the tag string "p" instead of the
  default function name. And in turn the function `tags_decorator`
  assumes that the parameter that will be passed in is the function
  being decorated, `get_text`.

It might be helpful for me to see the equivalent block of code in "non-decorator" form but I can't seem to wrap my head around what that would begin to look like. I also don't comprehend why `tags_decorator` and `func_wrapper` are both returned. What is the purpose of returning two different functions if a decorator only needs to return 1 function to wrap `get_text`.

As a side note, it really comes down to the following.

- Can this block be simplified to something less than a set of 3 functions?
- Can decorators accept more than 1 argument to simplify code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within limits, everything after the `@` is executed to *produce* a decorator. In your first example, what follows after the `@` is just a name:

```
@p_decorate
```

so Python looks up `p_decorate` and calls it with the decorated function as an argument:

```
get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
```

(oversimplified a bit, `get_text` is not initially bound to the original function, but you got the gist already).

In your second example, the decorator expression is a little more involved, it includes a call:

```
@tags("p")
```

so Python uses `tags("p")` to find the decorator. In the end this is what then is executed:

```
get_text = tags("p")(get_text)
```

The *output* of `tags("p")` is the decorator here! I call the `tags` function itself a decorator *factory*, it produces a decorator when called. When you call `tags()`, it returns `tags_decorator()`. That's the *real* decorator here.

You could instead remove the decorator function and hardcode the `"p"` value and use that directly:

```
def tags_decorator_p(func):
    def func_wrapper(name):
        return "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format("p", func(name))
    return func_wrapper

@tags_decorator_p
def get_text(name):
    # ...
```

but then you'd have to create separate decorators for each possible value of the argument to `tags()`. That's the value of a decorator factory, you get to add parameters to the decorator and alter how your function is decorated.

A decorator *factory* can take any number of arguments; it is just a function you call to produce a decorator. The decorator *itself* can only accept one argument, the function-to-decorate.

I said, *within limits* at the start of my answer for a reason; the syntax for the expression following the `@` only allows a dotted name (`foo.bar.baz`, so attribute access) and a call (`(arg1, arg2, keyword=arg3)`). See the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-decorator). The original [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) states:

> The decorator statement is limited in what it can accept -- arbitrary expressions will not work. Guido preferred this because of a gut feeling [17] .

Comment: Thank you. And I made a short edit after your response. Why exactly does these set of functions return 2 functions and not 1?

Comment: @Max: see my latest edit. One is the decorator (produced by the decorator factory), the other is the wrapper replacing the original function, the result of the decorator.

Comment: I understand now, the purpose of the 2 function calls. I am able to make a specific decorator with the decorator factory to further specify my final wrapper.